# angular wizard ng-view and angularui modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am building a wizard in angular using the angular-ui bootstrap modal component.
In my main page, I am already using ng-views for navigation.

The goal is to create a modal wizard on one of these pages. As far as I can see,
nested ng-views are not supported. If possible, I would like to keep each step of 
the wizard as an external resource.

A terrible way to accomplish this at the moment is something to this effect:

```
<div id="wizardModal"  class="modal hide">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(1)">
          <p>Step1 header</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(2)">
          <p>Step2 header</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(3)">
          <p>Step3 header</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(1)">
          <p>Step1 body</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(2)">
          <p>Step2 body</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(3)">
          <p>Step3 body</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(1)">
          <p>Step1 footer</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(2)">
          <p>Step2 footer</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="isCurrentStep(3)">
          <p>Step3 footer</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, the above is unacceptable and will create maintenance nightmares.
Is there a clean approach to accomplishing the same effect?

Comment: Why not just make this a directive that you can pass the current step into, which will then conditionally load different partials as a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ng-include worked like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tutorial about creating a wizard-style app using ng-view and ngRouter [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router).

I believe this approach is much better since you can have individual controllers per step that inherit the scope from the host form thus keeping all the data but separating the logic.